# Optimizing trigonometric equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

I've come across a problem from an old calculus textbook which goes like

A tool shed, $250\space cm$ high and $100\space cm$ deep is build against a wall. Calculate the shortest ladder length that can reach from the ground to the wall behind.

I got

$\text{length} = \frac{100}{cosx} + \frac{250}{sinx}$

Which I derived to get

$\text{Length'}=\frac{100sinx}{cos^2(x)} - \frac{250cosx}{sin^2(x)}$

Set that to equal 0 and got

$250\cos^3x=100\sin^3x$

And now stuck would like to know how to finish this problem!

Comment: Rewrite as $\tan^3 x=\frac{250}{100}$.

Comment: Yes, go on please :D

Comment: I did that already still very much stuck on how to evaluate that expression

Comment: You get $\tan x=(2.5)^{1/3}$.  So now we know $\tan x$, and can find exact expressions for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$, or use the calculator to find $x$ to many decimal places, then $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.

Comment: You are welcome. You were very close to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the answer, let me suppose that you need to compute $x$ and that you only have a very limited calculator (no trigonometric function available).

You obtained $\tan^3(x)=2.5$ which means $\tan(x)\approx 1.35721$ which means that $x$ is slightly larger than $\frac \pi 4$. So, consider Taylor expansion built at $x=\frac \pi 4$ $$\tan(x)=1+2 \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+2 \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^3\right)$$ So, ignoring higher terms, you need to solve $$1+2y+2y^2=\sqrt[3]{\frac{5}{2}}$$ where $y=x-\frac{\pi }{4}$. This gives $$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{5}-1}-1\right)\approx 0.154679$$ that is to say $x \approx 0.940077$ while the exact solution is $\approx 0.935793$ which is not too bad for the price of a quadratic.

Another way, may be simpler could be to consider that, from the series $$\tan^3(x)=1+6 \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+18 \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^3\right)$$ which leads to the equation $$1+6y+18y^2=\frac 52$$ from which $y=\frac 16$ and $x=\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac 16\approx 0.952065$. The result is worse in quality but nicer at least.

Comment: Is this highschool mathematics? Because that's the level I'm at, sorry I can't appreciate the full beauty of your solution built around having a cheap calculator. Regardless thanks for posting an interesting solution!

Comment: I took the problem as a small game since you solved it. In any manner, you are very welcome ! Cheers :-)